# Print row from table in R

Tags: r, printing, where-clause

I'm new in R, and I'm trying to display in console several columns from a row when a condition is fulfilled. I've searched through the internet and I couldn't find a proper solution. At the moment, I've tried the R where clause with little success.

Here's my script.

```
#Coordinates
northing <- 398380.16
easting <- 6873865.89

filePath = '/media/jgm/Toshiba\ HDD/SatelliteData/data/'
file = 'MOD09GQ_2006075.csv'
mydata <- read.table(paste(filePath,file, sep = ""),header=TRUE,sep=",")
mydata$'(x-northing)²' <- (mydata$x-northing)**2
mydata$'(y-easting)²' <- (mydata$y-easting)**2
mydata$'DISTANCE' <- sqrt(mydata$`(x-northing)²`+mydata$`(y-easting)²`)
minDistance <- min(mydata[,10], na.rm = T)
```

I want to display in console the value of the columns sur_refl_b01, sur_refl_b02, NDVI and NDVI_SCALED when the value of the column DISTANCE is minDistance.

Hope this table output helps.

[image]

Answer (score 0, accepted):

welcome to SO, try something like :

```
print(mydata[which(mydata$'DISTANCE'==minDistance),4:7])
```